# curl: why do I get empty response?

Tags: ssl, curl

I use google developer tool and copy the answer as curl request

[image]

WHen I run that curl on my linux server, I got **Empty reply from server**

```
curl 'https://web-ast.dsi.cnrs.fr/l3c/owa/personnel.liste?nom=&prenom=&code_labo=&p_dep=52&sec=&bap=&emptype=&nat_pers=&typ_pers=&organisme=&delegation=&ville=&p_i=0&p_nb_res=0' \
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br' -H 'Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,es;q=0.2,pl;q=0.2' \
-H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36' \
-H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' \
-H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
--compressed

curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Verbose Output:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 193.52.36.99...
* Connected to web-ast.dsi.cnrs.fr (193.52.36.99) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; CN=web-ast.dsi.cnrs.fr
*    start date: 2013-10-21 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2016-10-20 23:59:59 GMT
*    subjectAltName: web-ast.dsi.cnrs.fr matched
*    issuer: C=NL; O=TERENA; CN=TERENA SSL CA
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /l3c/owa/personnel.liste?nom=&prenom=&code_labo=&p_dep=52&sec=&bap=&emptype=&nat_pers=&typ_pers=&organisme=&delegation=&ville=&p_i=0&p_nb_res=0 HTTP/1.1
> Host: web-ast.dsi.cnrs.fr
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
> Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,es;q=0.2,pl;q=0.2
> Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
> Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
> Cache-Control: max-age=0
> Connection: keep-alive
> 
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host web-ast.dsi.cnrs.fr left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Any idea why ?

Comment: Hi Yarek, I added verbose output of the request and I have the same problem.  What OS and OpenSSL version are you using?  I'm on Mint 17.2 (Ubuntu 14.04) with OpenSSL 1.0.1f.  I wonder if this is related.  Gonna try on RHEL shortly and some other OpenSSL versions.  I even tried `openssl s_client -connect web-ast.dsi.cnrs.fr:443` and no matter what I sent (bogus data or valid HTTP request) the connection closes without sending any data back. `wget` suffers the same problem so it's not curl related, most likely OpenSSL.

Answer (score 0):

> -k, --insecure (SSL) This option explicitly allows curl to perform "insecure" SSL connections and transfers. All SSL connections are attempted to be made secure by using the CA certificate bundle installed by default. This makes all connections considered "insecure" fail unless -k, --insecure is used.

Try this bro.

Comment: Nah that's not it.  The TLS exchange happens fine, I tried a bunch of things earlier but it wasn't an SSL problem.

Comment: I tried in my local get success content. I don't know why you fail :(

Comment: @yarek Are you try curl to google or something simple than?