# CORS fails on request with OPTIONS (Response with status: 0)

Tags: curl, cors, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

<sup>Update: Rewrite of the question since I've got some new information. History is visible in the edits.</sup>

**Issue introduction**
I have a `django-rest-framework` application running on a subdomain `api.nrzonline.nl`. The frontend `ng2 + webpack` application is running on the domain itself `nrzonline.nl`. When sending a request with `ng2-restangular` to the API, I receive the following errors in my console:

```
 zone.js OPTIONS http://api.nrzonline.com/project/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
 EXCEPTION: Response with status: 0  for URL: null
```

**The current issue**
After quite some testing with curls, I found that all the requests fail when the preflight request with `OPTIONS` is send.

Request with `-X GET` works properly:

```
curl 'api.nrzonline.nl/skill/' -X GET
[{"id":1,"category":{"id":1,"title":"skill-a",...}]
```

(preflight) request with `-X OPTIONS` fails with no response

```
curl 'api.nrzonline.nl/skill/' -X OPTIONS
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Performing this `-x OPTIONS` request on the API on the Django development server locally works without any issue's.

**server settings**

- `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True`
- `CORS_ALLOW_METHODS` is on default, which allows `OPTIONS`
- `CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS` is on default

Middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

**What I have tried**

- I have read that it is possible that the server requires HTTPS request, but currently there is no SSL certificate active. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42837622/3202958)) Though, I did try to `curl` with `--insecure` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38465262/3202958))
- Sending the request as `text/plain` instead of `application/json` with `-H "Content-Type: text/plain"` ([source (comment on answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13030629/3202958))

**The question**
What am I missing / doing wrong, so that the preflight with `-X OPTIONS` is failing. Any tips, explanations or references to a possible solution  are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Answer credits go to my brother, hoster of my website</sub>

The issue was [DirectAdmin](https://www.directadmin.com/) related. By default DirectAdmin only allows `GET`, `POST` and `HEAD`.

These settings are found in `include /etc/nginx/webapps.conf;` as:

```
if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ) {
    return 444;
}
```

Adding `OPTIONS` should fix the problem. Remove or comment out the code block to allow any request method.

However, modifying `/etc/nginx/webapps.conf` might cause DirectAdmin to override this file during a new HTTPD update. The file `<path_to_directadmin>/custombuild/costum/nginx/conf` is used to generate a `conf` file. Making your modifications here should prevent loss of your adjustments.